# What is my 'voting ratio'?

Tags: support, voting

I recently noticed, after clicking on 'review', that SO tracks my progress towards the badges `Strunk & White`, `Copy Editor`, and `Electorate`.

Right below that it says `your voting is x.xx -- you are eligible`.

What is this number and how is it calculated?

Comment: Never mind, I derp'd - it is question votes / (question votes + answer votes) - I accidentally calculated question votes / answer votes.

Comment: @Nightfirecat -- `derp`'d it?  Nice, never heard of it before.  http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/derp#.TsFlfVYnR10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is calculated as

```
ratio = (# votes on questions) / (# total votes)
```

Answer (score 8):

To get "Electorate", you need at least 600 votes on questions, and your votes on questions must account for at least 25% of the total votes you have cast.

To that end, I imagine that the voting ratio represents the ratio of your question votes over total votes, for the purposes of getting Electorate. Yours, I would imagine at the time of this, would be around ~65%.

Comment: Is this in the FAQ somewhere?

Comment: it is in the badge description @MattFenwick

Comment: @waffles -- it says there "Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions."  I had inferred that that was the "vote ratio", but I wanted to confirm that.